# Record execution of .Net program in order to debug through it at a later point in time

Tags: .net, clr

I have an integration test and during the execution quite a lot of data originates due to the behaviour of the system under test. Depending on the test run result this data is valuable or not. I therefore have the problem that I must find some "structure" (for every test this would be some other structure I have to come up with because there are many different tests with different data) to store the data in because I might need it - mostly in a later point in time - in order to look it up again.

For me the best (yet I assume quite heavy-weighted in terms of disk usage) solution would be to record the execution (serializing the generated data over time) and have a possibility to "virtually" step through the run any time afterwards.

Is there a tool or a concept with which I can accomplish this or is there some crutial part I'm missing or mistaken about? Looking forward to your input.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains dotTrace https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ or RedGate ANTS Profiler http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/ are very good for this type of analysis.

Comment: I do not want to know which method in my code takes how long to execute or how much memory it consumes. As far as I know this is what these tools do so they won't help me unless you convince me of the contrary.

Comment: These tools will certainly give you a browsable call stack of your application. If you want convincing then try them. Both tools have a free trial so take a few hours and see if they provide what you require.

Comment: I have installed dotTrace and it gives me only how long which method took to execute (including a percentage of the total run time) and how often which method was called. The profiling options in the Professional version are wall time (CPU instruction or performance counter), thread time and thread cycle time.Unfortunately I haven't found nothing like a browsable stack frame set with debug info on the different values my variables carried over run time.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access the browsable call stacks you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The closest technology i know is code coverage. [dotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/#results) can take tracing snapshot while executing your test and give you all information about executed lines in your program. And it's not that heavy as writing all debug information for future "playing" same scenario.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken dotCover is just a unit test runner and code coverage tool so this won't help me either - I'm sorry. It shows which line of code were executed during test execution but will not show me what value a variable carried (not even speaking about the sequence of values my variable carried throughout the entire runtime - maybe I passed some line twice like in a for-loop) even if the corresponding line was covered by my test.

Comment: Yes that is true. I doubt that is make sense to get whole memory dump after each instruction to get your local values, but maybe there is a tool that can get values on specific depth of search from local roots. 

P.S: Did you check MS VS Ultimate's IntelliTrace? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will have a look at it.